# IO location vs Memory region

Tags: linux, memory, io

As I was going through the section `Accessing the I/O and Memory Spaces` [in the chapter PCI Drivers](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch12.pdf), page #15, I wondered what exactly is the difference between IO location and Memory region.

Here are the first two sentences...

```
A PCI device implements up to six I/O address regions. Each region consists of either
memory or I/O locations.
```

I would like to know the difference between memory and I/O location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is generally how the device is addressed. The term 'location' in your question generally refers to the device mapping, i.e., whether the device is I/O mapped or memory mapped.

The difference between the two is that the I/O mapped I/O uses dedicated instructions and control signals to access the I/O space, whereas the memory mapped I/O uses the same instructions that are used to access the memory, in which case, the data instead of going(or coming) to the memory location goes to the device.

As far as PCI devices are concerned, it is capable of mapping to both I/O as well as memory regions. One can view the mapping using `lspci -v`.

As a sample output :

`01:0c.2 Parallel controller: NetMos Technology PCI 9865 Multi-I/O Controller (prog-if 03 [IEEE1284])
    Subsystem: Device a000:2000
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20
    I/O ports at ed00 [size=8]
    I/O ports at ec00 [size=8]
    Memory at fddfa000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at fddf9000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: parport_pc
    Kernel modules: parport_pc`

Above output show the output of a PCI based parallel port. Here we can see that the ports are mapped to both I/O regions as well as memory regions. Either of the two mechanisms could be used to access the device registers. Out of six I/O regions that the device could address, it is using four (two I/O mapped and two memory mapped).

Comment: If the Memory regions are missing in the output of 'lspci -vv' (I mean 'Memory at fddfa000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K], Memory at fddf9000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]'), while I still have a Memory Interface Generator in my design with different BARs, what could be the reason?
Reference to my q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53479150/memory-regions-not-displayed-in-lspci-vv-while-using-axi-bridge-for-pci-expr